# Methods to Load Saved Python List in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I have a question on how to load saved python lists in Pytorch. The reference environment is Google Colab.

Suppose I saved the regular list as follows.

```
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
training_sets = ["a","b","c"]
model_save_name = 'training_sets.pt'
path = F"/content/gdrive/My Drive/Documents" 
torch.save(training_sets,path)
```

Does pytorch support loading for regular python lists? Or does it only apply for pytorch tensors?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Of course yes!**
You can save any kind of python object using *torch.save*

**Example**

```
import torch
a = [1,2,3]
torch.save(a,'a.pth')
b = torch.load('a.pth')
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
```